# Big O-notation proof: show that $x^{2}+5x+11$ is $O(x^{3})$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Show that $x^{2}+5x+11$ is $O(x^{3})$ by providing the smallest value of the witness $C$ such that $|f(x)|≤C|g(x)|$ whenever $x>11$.

What's the value of $C$?

Comment: What are the values of $|f(x)|$ and $|g(x)|$ when $x=11$?  Then put those values into the inequality $|f(x)|\le C|g(x)|$ and solve for $C$.

Comment: Therefore the value of C is 1/7?

Comment: Can you show that $|f(x)|\le \frac17|g(x)|$ whenever $x>11$, and that  $|f(x)|\gt C'|g(x)|$ for some $x>11$ if $C' > \frac17$?

Comment: Yes, when x = 11, the f(x) <= 1/7 g(x). In addition, the derivative of the former one is: 2x^2+5 and the latter one is 3x^2. So the latter one is faster.